# Docker and --userns-remap, how to manage volume permissions to share data between host and container?

Tags: docker

In docker, files created inside containers tend to have unpredictable ownership while inspecting them from the host. The owner of the files on a volume is root (uid 0) by default, but as soon as non-root user accounts are involved in the container and writing to the file system, owners become more or less random from the host perspective.

It is a problem when you need to access volume data from the host using the same user account which is calling the docker commands.

Typical workarounds are

- forcing users uIDs at creation time in Dockerfiles (non portable)
- passing the UID of the host user to the `docker run` command as an environment variable and then running some `chown` commands on the volumes in an entrypoint script.

Both these solutions can give some control over the actual permissions outside the container.

I expected user namespaces to be the final solution to this problem. I have run some tests with the recently released version 1.10 and --userns-remap set to my desktop account. However, I am not sure that it can make file ownership on mounted volumes easier to deal with, I am afraid that it could actually be the opposite.

Suppose I start this basic container

```
docker run -ti -v /data debian:jessie /bin/bash
echo 'hello' > /data/test.txt
exit
```

And then inspect the content from the host :

```
ls -lh /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/volumes/<some-id>/_data/

-rw-r--r-- 1 100000 100000 6 Feb  8 19:43 test.txt
```

This number '100000' is a sub-UID of my host user, but since it does not correspond to my user's UID, I still can't edit test.txt without privileges. This sub-user does not seem to have any affinity with my actual regular user outside of docker. It's not mapped back.

The workarounds mentioned earlier in this post which consisted of aligning UIDs between the host and the container do not work anymore due to the `UID->sub-UID` mapping that occurs in the namespace.

Then, is there a way to run docker with user namespace enabled (for improved security), while still making it possible for the host user running docker to own the files generated on volumes?

Comment: I think that if you are going to be sharing volumes between the host and the container that user namespaces are *not* going to be part of the solution.  Your second option ("passing the UID of the host user to the docker run command as an environment variable and then running some chown commands on the volumes in an entrypoint script") is probably the best solution.

Comment: Docker itself does not seem to encourage using host-mounted writable volumes. Since I am not running a cloud service and only using my own trusted images, I am now wondering if the security benefit of user NS is worth sacrifying so much convenience.

Comment: @StéphaneC. have you found a better approach perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not using user namespace and passing UIDs from the host is still my option of choice. I hope there will be a proper way to map users in the future. I doubt it but still, I keep an eye open.

Comment: Anyone tried `--userns=host` when running `docker run`? [issue `--userns=host`](https://github.com/hashicorp/nomad/issues/1904#issuecomment-523295864)

Answer (score 61):

If you can prearrange users and groups in advance, then it's possible to assign UIDs and GIDs in such specific way so that host users correspond to namespaced users inside containers.

Here's an example (Ubuntu 14.04, Docker 1.10):

1. Create some users with fixed numeric IDs:

   ```
   useradd -u 5000 ns1

   groupadd -g 500000 ns1-root
   groupadd -g 501000 ns1-user1

   useradd -u 500000 -g ns1-root ns1-root
   useradd -u 501000 -g ns1-user1 ns1-user1 -m
   ```
2. Manually edit auto-generated subordinate ID ranges in `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` files:

   ```
   ns1:500000:65536
   ```

   (note there are no records for `ns1-root` and `ns1-user1` due to `MAX_UID` and `MAX_GID` limits in `/etc/login.defs`)
3. Enable user namespaces in `/etc/default/docker`:

   ```
   DOCKER_OPTS="--userns-remap=ns1"
   ```

   Restart daemon `service docker restart`, ensure `/var/lib/docker/500000.500000` directory is created.

   **Now, inside containers you have `root` and `user1`, and on the host -- `ns1-root` and `ns1-user1`, with matching IDs**

   **UPDATE:** to guarantee that non-root users have fixed IDs in containers (e.g. user1 1000:1000), create them explicitly during image build.

Test-drive:

1. Prepare a volume directory

   ```
   mkdir /vol1
   chown ns1-root:ns1-root /vol1
   ```
2. Try it from a container

   ```
   docker run --rm -ti -v /vol1:/vol1 busybox sh
   echo "Hello from container" > /vol1/file
   exit
   ```
3. Try from the host

   ```
   passwd ns1-root
   login ns1-root
   cat /vol1/file
   echo "can write" >> /vol1/file
   ```

Not portable and looks like a hack, but works.

Comment: Very interesting and deserves a +1. But you'd still need to make sure that user1 in your image is assigned UID 1000. Otherwise you can not be sure that it will receive UID 501000 on the host. Btw are we absolutely sure that the formula is always `subUID lower bound + UID in image` if we are running many different images with an user having ID set to 1000?

Comment: @StéphaneC. Good point! Added a note about fixing IDs inside images. As for formula, I'm going to experiment further with my own images and will update the answer if find anything

Comment: If you arrange users and groups by hand in host and in containers, do you really need the "user namespace" feature ?

Comment: The namespace you create separates hosts users from container users, but you may need multiple namespace for containers, especially when official images (like the mysql one) create a user without explicit uid. How do you deal with multiple namespaces when the --userns-remap option expects only one ?

Comment: @amartynov May I ask why you took the trouble to specify a UID (5000) for your "ns1" user? Since it's the name (not the UID) that you reference in the subuid and subgid files, it seems like it shouldn't matter what UID this user gets. Am I missing some relationship, as the similarity between 5000 and 500000 might suggest?

Comment: @Jollymorphic You are right, the UID is not necessary, and I can't remember why I specified it. It's even better to not create "ns1" at all but to use the default "dockremap" which Docker creates automatically.

Comment: I've run into the bug where it appears that named volumes even though technically they should be using the same "root" user that my container is, don't allow me to write files into the volume and are giving me an access denied, which is silly because I'm using the root user in the container. Very strange and I'm going to see about reporting it or at least figuring out why I'm hitting this after enabling the `userns-remap` option.

Comment: @StéphaneC. I think the formula is correct. All containers share the dockremap UID space. So every root user in every container will get the UID "subUID" lower bound, every default UID (1000) of every container will get subUID ower bound + 1000, etc. Another issue is whether that rule will continue through docker versions or it will change to support more granularity (for instance, I expect docker will allow each container have its own user remapping space by subdividing the subID range into subgroups; I think that increment of functionality would makes sense).

Answer (score 6):

One workaround is to dynamically assign user's uid on build time to match the host.

Example `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
# Defines argument which can be passed during build time.
ARG UID=1000
# Create a user with given UID.
RUN useradd -d /home/ubuntu -ms /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u $UID ubuntu
# Switch to ubuntu user by default.
USER ubuntu
# Check the current uid of the user.
RUN id
# ...
```

Then build as:

```
docker build --build-arg UID=$UID -t mycontainer .
```

and run as:

```
docker run mycontainer
```

---

If you've existing container, create a wrapper container with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM someexistingcontainer
ARG UID=1000
USER root
# This assumes you've the existing user ubuntu.
RUN usermod -u $UID ubuntu
USER ubuntu
```

This can be wrapped in `docker-compose.yml` like:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  myservice:
    command: id
    image: myservice
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
    - /data:/data:rw
```

Then build and run as:

```
docker-compose build --build-arg UID=$UID myservice; docker-compose run myservice
```

Comment: I wouldn't want to look unfriendly but this is actually one of the workarounds listed in the original question, but not a solution and not related to user namespaces.

Comment: "at build time" does not feel dynamic to me. I have this filesharing problem with images that I did not even build myself.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases the Docker image is shared widely and can't be modified. I've been using a "brute force" approach that *dynamically creates a matching user inside the container* everytime it is started and switches to it. It's admittedly ugly but it takes only 50 lines of code and has been working well:

https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/blob/0a4b1d62d5b31b41/scripts/sudo-cwd.sh

Answer (score -1):

You can avoid permission problems by using the [`docker cp` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

> Ownership is set to the user and primary group at the destination. For example, files copied to a container are created with `UID:GID` of the root user. Files copied to the local machine are created with the `UID:GID` of the user which invoked the `docker cp` command.

Here is your example switched to use `docker cp`:

```
$ docker run -ti -v /data debian:jessie /bin/bash
root@e33bb735a70f:/# echo 'hello' > /data/test.txt
root@e33bb735a70f:/# exit
exit
$ docker volume ls
DRIVER              VOLUME NAME
local               f073d0e001fb8a95ad8d919a5680e72b21a457f62a40d671b63c62ae0827bf93
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/docker/100000.100000/volumes/f073d0e001fb8a95ad8d919a5680e72b21a457f62a40d671b63c62ae0827bf93/_data
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 100000 100000 6 Oct  6 10:34 test.txt
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED              STATUS                          PORTS               NAMES
e33bb735a70f        debian:jessie       "/bin/bash"         About a minute ago   Exited (0) About a minute ago                       determined_hypatia
$ docker cp determined_hypatia:/data/test.txt .
$ ls -l test.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 don don 6 Oct  6 10:34 test.txt
$ cat test.txt
hello
$
```

However, if you just want to read files out of a container, you don't need the named volume. This example uses a named container instead of a named volume:

```
$ docker run -ti --name sandbox1 debian:jessie /bin/bash
root@93d098233cf3:/# echo 'howdy' > /tmp/test.txt
root@93d098233cf3:/# exit
exit
$ docker cp sandbox1:/tmp/test.txt .
$ ls -l test.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 don don 6 Oct  6 10:52 test.txt
$ cat test.txt
howdy
$
```

I find named volumes useful when I want to copy files into a container, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46596523/4794).

Comment: But `docker cp` involves duplicating data. Moreover, according to the doc, when copying data to a container it sets ownership IDs according to the root user, which is often not the account running the containerized app. I fail to see how it solves our problem.

Comment: You're right, @Stéphane, it involves duplicating data. However, making copies of the files lets you assign different ownership and permissions on the host and in the container. `docker cp` gives you full control over file ownership when you stream a tar archive into or out of a container. You can adjust the ownership and permissions of each entry in the tar file as you stream it, so you're not limited to the root user.