# Docker user namespacing map user in container to host

Tags: postgresql, docker, namespaces, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'd like to map user postgres or root inside container to user myuser on the host. There's a lot of references to this online, but it is not very clear to me how to achieve the following:

Is there a simple way to map arbitrary user inside container to user in host by a simple command line flag at the docker-run level

**Map root user inside container to myuser on host**

```
docker run --user-remap "mysuser:root" -p 6379:6379 redis:alpine
```

and

**Map postgres inside container to myuser on host**

```
docker run -it -p 5431:5432 --user-remap "myuser:postgres" --rm -v /home/myuser/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.6.0
```

I do not want to apply the same settings to all my containers. So doing this at the docker daemon level by applying

```
sudo docker daemon --userns-remap myuser
```

and updating /etc/passwd, /etc/group, /etc/subuid, /etc/subgid would not help solve my problem. Is there a way to solve this problem at the `docker run` stage, so that these settings can be applied on a container by container basis.

Thanks

Comment: This post addresses part of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35291520/docker-and-userns-remap-how-to-manage-volume-permissions-to-share-data-betwee
But I dont have an option to preset the uid/gid in the host in my scenario

Answer (score 7):

No, if you want to use user-namespaces, there's currently no way to remap the user for bind-mounted directories and files.

Basically, the issue you're running into is the exact *goal* of user namespaces; preventing a privileged user inside a container to get access to files on the host. This protects you from a process being able to escape the container from doing damage on the host.

*However* it looks like your goal is to give the *postgres* user access to files on your host, which are owned by a local user. For that situation, there may be another approach; run the container with the same `uid:gid` as the user that owns the files on the host. This may require changes to the image (because some parts in the images are currently created with the `postgres` user, which currently has a different `uid:gid` (also see some information about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245216/write-in-shared-volumes-docker/29251160#29251160))

Currently, doing so with the `postgres` official image requires some manual changes, but a pull request was recently merged for the official `postgres` image that makes this work out of the box (see [`docker-entrypoint.sh#L30-L41`](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/d7accc9c8c7d740ad756b887225fe31286d98f64/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L30-L41))

You can find details on the pull request; https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/pull/253, and the associated documentation; https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/802. This change should be available soon, but in the meantime you can create a custom image that extends the official PostgreSQL image.