# What is the significance of the user in `/etc/sub{u,g}id`? (Help me grok user namespaces)

Tags: linux, docker, linux-namespaces

I would like to ensure that any user inside my docker container always maps to a specific user on my docker host. I have tried using this reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/35854547/1020678

The user name in `/etc/subuid` seems to be used strictly as a key for mapping to the value: `<start id>:<range>`, but apart from that it seems to serve no purpose..

What really confuses me is the need of a user in `/etc/subuid`, when this user doesn't seem to have permission to write to the filesystem when mounting volumes in the docker container.

Having followed the example in the link, I do the following as the user `ns1`:

`$ mkdir test && docker run -ti -v $(pwd)/test:/tmp alpine touch /tmp/foobar`

returns: `touch: /tmp/foobar: Permission denied`

It seems like the user `ns1` has no benefits of `--userns-remap=ns1`, so then why is this user required when enabling user namespaces for `ns1-root` and `ns1-user1`? These users can write to the docker volume when permissions are set correctly, but why not `ns1`?

Is it possible to achieve my goal, or do I have to explicitly define all users/groups both inside and outside my container, using the offset of the start id in `/etc/subuid` (500000 in the example I linked to)?

Comment: I believe the answer lies in the newuidmap command, but I have been trying to understand this for a few months and I'm still stuck :P